# Spectrum of right shift minus left shift operator on $\ell^2 (\mathbb{Z})$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory

Let $A:\ell^2(\mathbb Z) \longmapsto  \ell^2(\mathbb Z)$ be defined as following $A(x)_{n} = x_{n−1} − x_{n+1}$

Find A's spectrum. $\sigma(A)=\sigma_c(A)=\sigma_{ess}(A)=[-2i,2i]$

Operator is not self-adjoined, $A=S_r-S_l$ and $||A||=2$.

The space $\ell^2(\mathbb Z)$ is isomorphic with $L^2(\mathbb T)$, via the identification $\delta_n\longmapsto (t\mapsto e^{in\pi\,t})$.

$S_r$ mapped to $M_z$, $S_l$ mapped to $M_z^{-1}$
So the spectrum of $S_r-S_l$ is the same as that of $M_{z^{-1} - z}$.

I don't understand why  $$\sigma_c(M_f)=\sigma(M_f)=\overline{f(\mathbb R)}.$$ Why for a multiplication operator, its spectrum is the closure of the range? And spectrum continuous?

$$\sigma(S_r-S_l)=\overline{\{z-z^{-1}:\ z\in\mathbb T\}}
=\overline{\{z -\bar z:\ |z|=1\}}=\overline{\{2 \text{Im}\,z:\ |z|=1\}}$$
How to prove from that  that $\sigma_c=[-2i;2i]$?

Comment: It is a basic property of the multiplication operators. See for example the book of Teschl, https://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~gerald/ftp/book-schroe/schroe.pdf, pg. 74. He mentions the "essential range" of the function $f$, which in your case is continuous, so the essential range is $\overline{f(\mathbb R)}$.